# Fix HLS downloaded video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded a video from an stream (HLS) into an mp4 file.

The default Windows 10 Photo application plays the video without any problem.
But "Midia Player Classic" and "VLC Player" are unable to play it.

I'm trying to convert the video with ffmpeg to play it into an tablet for my kid.

Below is the output from ffmpeg

I tried specify the source format, codec and rate, but didn´t work.
Also I tried to specify the duration of the video without success.
Can anyone help me?

**Convert Output**

```
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x56121fa2dd80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x316376  61), none, 1280x720, 3037 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '12e01 Primo Ludovico.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41mp42
  Duration: 00:28:33.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3170 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3037 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97   tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : dailymotion/hls.js
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
**Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF**4:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
Error marking filters as finished
[aac @ 0x56121fa58f80] Qavg: 216.471
[aac @ 0x56121fa58f80] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

**Video Information:**

```
    root@atom:~# ffmpeg -i video.mp4
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x561b8b0f2840] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3037 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '12e01 Primo Ludovico.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41mp42
  Duration: 00:28:33.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3170 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3037 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : dailymotion/hls.js
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

**Trying to increase probe as suggested by @Gyan (result: only audio)**

```
root@atom:~# ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 50M -y -i video.mp4 -c copy new.mp4
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ab30d17a00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3037 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41mp42
  Duration: 00:28:33.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3170 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3037 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : dailymotion/hls.js
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'new.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41mp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 3037 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : dailymotion/hls.js
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   27060kB time=00:28:33.30 bitrate= 129.4kbits/s speed= 545x
video:0kB audio:26771kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.080556%
```

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 50M -i video.mp4 -c copy new.mp4`

Comment: It almost worked. But it stops at 27BM (the video has 648MB)

Comment: Share the log..

Comment: Added to the post because it's long. 27MB is the size of the audio.